# Some question about a new type of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

> Let $G$ be a simple graph such that some of its vertices are like a fork. i.e. there is vertices $w,x,a,v$ such that edges $[v,w]$ and $[w,a]$ are incident in $w$ and edges  $[w,a]$ and $[x,w]$ are incident (and so adjacent) in $w$ but $[w,x]$ and $[v,w]$ are not adjacent. (see the following figure)

[image]

**Question:** Does this type of *graphs* have a name? What is the chromatic index(edge coloring number) of this type of *graphs*?

**Motivation:** Consider a Internet Bank service such that there is a server $w$ (bank) and users $v$ (customer) and $x$ (customer). Each user can access to own account in server, but no two user can access to each other.

Comment: I don't understand how there can be two vertices with the same name. There also seems to be a trivalent vertex that is not represented by a thick dot, just above the two $w$'s.
Is the meaning of *adjacent* different to *incident*? Do you consider only planar graphs? Maybe you mean *some of whose \textbf{edges} are like a fork?*

Comment: All of graphs. The adjacent  and incident are in it usual meaning.  I don't understand   "There also  a trivalent vertex that is not represented." can be there or there is in picture?

Comment: A "usual" graph can be equivalently given by the set of *flags*, together with an equivalence relation (its equivalence classes being vertices) and a free involution (its orbits being edges). If you want something unusual like in this question, you can start with this and then replace equivalence relation with a cover and involutions with something more weird

Comment: In my dictionary the "usual meaning" of "adjacent" is this: Two (distinct) edges are adjacent if they share a common vertex.  So if $x\not=v$, then the two edge $[x,w]$ and $[v,w]$ are adjacent, since they share the vertex $w$.

Comment: In fact for this particular feature you may leave edges undisturbed (i. e. they will be orbits of a free involution on flags). It is that vertices will be now possibly intersecting elements of a cover of the set of flags. For your picture, the flags will be $x_a,x_w,w_x,w_a,w_v,a_x,a_w,a_v,v_a,v_w,...$, with the involution interchanging each pair $(p_q,q_p)$, and vertices will be $\{x_a,x_w,...\}$, $\{w_a,w_x\}$, $\{w_a,w_v\}$, $\{a_x,a_w,a_v\}$, $\{v_w,v_a,...\}$, ...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, thanks for your comment. can you introduce some references?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think I have seen this somewhere but cannot remember where

Comment: I mean this relaxing from equivalence relations to covers. As for defining graphs in terms of flags, see e. g. references at the [nLab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+graph) about generalized graphs

Comment: I am not familiar with hypergraphs, Isn't this a hypergraph?

Comment: I don't see how hypergraphs can help with the need to have several nodes under the same name.

Comment: Why did you represent the vertex $w$ with two dots instead of one?  Why did you represent the edge $[w,a]$ with three lines instead of one?

Comment: The usual meanings I am familiar with are "Two vertices are called adjacent if they are connected by an edge" and "Two edges are called incident, if they share a vertex."  So what do you mean when you say that two *edges* are *adjacent*?

Comment: you can argue yourself  all things that I want by reading the motivation.

Answer (score 1):

Define a *multiflag graph* to be a triple $G=(F,\mathscr V,\tau)$ consisting of some set $F$, called the set of *flags* of $G$; some subset $\mathscr V\subseteq\mathscr PF$ of the powerset of $F$, called the set of *vertices* of $G$, and a free involution $\tau:F\to F$ on flags. Here, $\mathscr V$ is required to be a *cover* of $F$, that is, $\bigcup\mathscr V=F$.

Every "ordinary" undirected graph $(V,E)$ gives rise to such a structure, with $F$ the incidence relation of the graph, that is, the set of pairs $(v,e)$ where $e\in E$ is an edge and $v\in V$ is a vertex of $e$. Here $\mathscr V$ consists of the sets $F_v:=\{(v,e)\mid\text{$v$ is a vertex of $e$}\}$, one for each $v\in V$ (since $F_v\ne F_{v'}$ for $v\ne v'$, one might identify $V$ with $\mathscr V$). Moreover $\tau(v,e)=(v',e)$ where $v'$ is the (unique) vertex of $e$ different from $v$.

It is well known that in this way one obtains a one-to-one correspondence between undirected graphs and those multiflag graphs for which $\mathscr V$ is not only a cover but also a *partition* of $F$, i.e. satisfies $F_1\cap F_2=\varnothing$ for $F_1\ne F_2$, $F_1,F_2\in\mathscr V$. In this case to each element of $F$ corresponds a unique element of $\mathscr V$ (the one containing it), and one usually pictures flags as "half-edges" $\bullet\!-$, with $\tau$ interchanging two half-edges forming an edge (like ${\bullet\!-}{-\!\bullet}$).

If one drops this additional restriction one can include examples like yours: for

[image]

we would have

$F=\{p_x,p_q,q_p,q_v,v_q,v_a,v_w,w_v,w_a,w_x,x_w,x_a,x_p,a_x,a_w,a_v\}$,

$\mathscr V=\{\{p_x,p_q\},\{q_p,q_v\},\{v_q,v_a,v_w\},\{w_v,w_a\},\{w_x,w_a\},\{x_w,x_a,x_p\}\}$

and

$\tau(i_j)=j_i$ for all $i_j\in F$.

This does not give rise to an ordinary graph since $\{w_v,w_a\}\cap\{w_x,w_a\}\ne\varnothing$; one can say that the flag $w_a$ is "two-headed", i. e. describes a "half-edge" with two "heads".

Comment: Thanks. but what is the chromatic index  of this type of  graphs (multiflag graphs)?

Comment: You can extend the definition of chromatic index in various ways. Which one is suitable for you depends on how are you going to use it. One possible definition is to call edges $(i_j,j_i)$ and $(k_l,l_k)$ adjacent if there is an element of $\mathscr V$ containing either both $i_j$ and $k_l$, or both $i_j$ and $l_k$, or both $j_i$ and $k_l$, or both $j_i$ and $l_k$. Another (nonequivalent) definition would be to call them adjacent if either $i=k$ or $i=l$ or $j=k$ or $j=l$. There might be other possibilities too. After you have chosen definition of adjacency, chromatic index is defined as usual